# sort by name (slug) custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, sort, slug

What's wrong in this query ? the sortby=name doesn't change anything.

```
$the_query = 'posts_per_page=-1&sortby=name&order=ASC&post_type=mycustom&custom_cat=mycat';
// query is made               
query_posts($the_query);
```

Comment: Word of advice, never use `query_posts`. Use `WP_Qeury` or `pre_get_posts` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "sort" query param is usually "orderby" not "sortby", to match the SQL `ORDER BY` clause.

Perhaps try:

```
$the_query = 'posts_per_page=-1&orderby=name&order=ASC&post_type=mycustom&custom_cat=mycat';
```

It's also possible that the value you are passing is incorrect, but without knowing the details of your custom post type there's not much else I can suggest.